# PHP - fetch value of specified key pair in mulit-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

hopefully a easy one for you,

my sql query is returning a mulit-dimensional array, I need to access only one key the is nested on the second level but cant figure out how.

here is my function.

```
public function get_visitor_id($id)
{
  $this->db->where('mobile',$id);
  $this->db->or_where('email',$id);
  $this->db->select('uid');
  $result = $this->db->get('visitors');
  if ($result)
  {
    foreach ($result->result() as $key=>$value){
      $array[$key] = $value;
    }
    var_dump($array);
    return $array;
  }
}
```

The array returned is

```
{ [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (1) { ["uid"]=> string(2) "24" } }
```

I only need the value of ['uid'] so in essence if I was to echo get_visitor_id() it would evaluate to "24".

Thanks for you help.

Cheers

Comment: may i ask why you using `$array`?

Comment: What library is `$this->db`? Is this Laravel?

Comment: xYuri, Im not sure if I needed to, but im still quite new to programming so thought it would be easiest to loop through the results and add them to an array and then return only that key's value. I am open to a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**try changing `foreach()` func to:**

```
foreach($result as $res){
$res = $res->fetch_assoc();
$array['uid'] = $res['uid'];}
```

**EDIT:** in case of this didn't work then try while loop:

```
while($res = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $array['uid'] = $res['uid'];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like he's using mysqli. I think it's Laravel.

Comment: if so, i wont be much useful in that case :(

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. I am using codeignitor and its built in library

Comment: well try it and tell me what you got ;) hope it helps